# Why re.findall only return first ten rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I try to match the string with using regex from 59k rows. Off course I expected the same 59k rows as the result. However the result only return first 10 rows.

I feels this a silly questions, but still wondering what's wrong here.

```
y = str(data[['geometry']])
z = re.findall("(?<=\()\d.*(?=\))", y)
```

[image]

Comment: Because the string representation of the pandas dataframe column truncates the data.

Comment: You can use the built in [series.str.findall method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) which is designed exactly for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own solution with using loop:

```
location = []
for l in data['geometry']:
    latlon = re.findall("(?<=\()\d.*(?=\))", l)
    location.append(z)


df_latlon = DataFrame(location)
df_latlon
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `str.findall` with `tolist()`

**Ex:**

```
data['geometry'].str.findall("(?<=\()\d.*(?=\))").tolist()
```

**Demo:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'geometry': ['aa (123) bb (1.5)', 'aa (123) bb (1.5)', 'aa (123) bb (1.5)', 'aa (123) bb (1.5)']})
print(df['geometry'].str.findall("(?<=\()(\d.*?)(?=\))").tolist())
```

**Output:**

```
[['123', '1.5'], ['123', '1.5'], ['123', '1.5'], ['123', '1.5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extract`:

```
data['geometry'].str.extract(r'\((\d.*)\)', expand=False).tolist()
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CVHnO7/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```